# Enhance Sql Server Procedure Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have the following procedure and it's performance is kinda slow when I execute it for long range of time for big data
I have table and storing records of Cars parking
the table contains millions of records

I hope everything is clear and I can find some help to improve performance of my query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Report_Parking]
@PageNumber        INT = 1, 
@PageSize          INT = 50, 
@StartTime         int = 0 , --I'm using unix timestamp
@EndTime           int = 0, 
@ColumnSort       NVARCHAR(50), 
@OrderSort         NVARCHAR(50),
@CarIDs          NVARCHAR(max)--array of cars

AS 
SET nocount ON 
SET fmtonly OFF 
BEGIN 
    
    CREATE TABLE #parkingTmp 
    (
        ID            int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        rownum            bigInt,
        CarID             NVARCHAR(23) NOT NULL,
        Start_Time        DateTime, 
        End_Time          DateTime,
        Parking_Time      NVARCHAR(50),
        Address       NVARCHAR(max),
        Long          NVARCHAR(20),
        Lat       NVARCHAR(20),
        Plate_Number      NVARCHAR(max),
        PageCounts    bigInt
    )
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

    SET @query+= N'insert into #parkingTmp 
                SELECT   * FROM [dbo].CarsParking 
                WHERE   ((EndTimeParking BETWEEN '+cast(@StartTime as varchar)+' AND '+cast(@EndTime as varchar)+') and [CarID] in('''+@CarIDs +''')'
    exec(@query)

    -- insert default records for not found cars 
    Declare @Id nvarchar(23)
    Declare @Ids Table (id nvarchar(23) primary Key not null)
    Insert @Ids(id) select * from [dbo].[SplitStrings_ToList](@CarIDs,',') 
    delete from @ids  
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT CarID FROM #parkingTmp)
    
    While exists (Select * From @Ids)
    Begin
        Select @Id = MAX(id) from @Ids
        
        INSERT INTO #parkingTmp 
        SELECT  top 1 *
        FROM CarsParking T
        WHERE CarID = @Id
        order by Start_Time DESC 
        
        Delete from @Ids Where id = @Id
    End
    --- end inserting 

    -- select final result with paging
    DECLARE @FirstRec INT= (@PageNumber -1) * @PageSize; 
    DECLARE @LastRec INT= @PageNumber * @PageSize +1;
    
    declare @sql nvarchar(Max)=''    
    SET @sql = N'WITH ctepaging AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Plate_Number,'+@ColumnSort+' '+@OrderSort+') AS rownumber,* FROM #parkingTmp)'
    SET @sql += ' SELECT * FROM ctepaging '
    SET @sql += ' WHERE  rownumber > '+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), @FirstRec) + ' AND rownumber < ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), @LastRec)
        
    exec sp_executesql @sql 
END
```

I added index on ID which is primary key by default and
also non clustered index in these columns which I filter on where statement CarID,ParkingTime
it improves the performance to procedure so it's taking 1 minute for 100k records now
before it was taking more than 5 mins
[taking 1 minute for 100k records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEWlJ.png) 
but still the performance is not that good

[here's a sample of data generated by script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAxuM.png)

Comment: Can you add a sample subset of the generated script that's slow to your question? We don't need your 100k records, but you could share a sample of 20 such record insertion so we will have a better idea of what gets slow. Have you considered indexing `CarID` as well?

Comment: start by rewriting the while loop, it's job can be performed by a regular join me thinks

Comment: actually, start by just fetching data by carId and dates directly, why do it in two steps

Comment: i think your whole procedure can be rewritten as one select

Comment: @LajosArpad already added a sample of data 
and yes I already mentioned that I've created index for CarID and ParkingTime records

Comment: @siggemannen could you explain your idea  
how to implement that

Answer (score 1):

I would probably write something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Report_Parking]
@PageNumber        INT = 1, 
@PageSize          INT = 50, 
@StartTime         int = 0 , --I'm using unix timestamp
@EndTime           int = 0, 
@ColumnSort       NVARCHAR(50), 
@OrderSort         NVARCHAR(50),
@CarIDs          NVARCHAR(max)--array of cars

AS 
SET nocount ON 
SET fmtonly OFF 
BEGIN 
   
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
    ,   @FirstRec INT= (@PageNumber -1) * @PageSize
    ,   @LastRec INT= @PageNumber * @PageSize +1;
    
    create table #IDs (id nvarchar(23) primary key)
    
    insert into #IDs (
        id
    )
    SELECT  DISTINCT * 
    from    [dbo].[SplitStrings_ToList](@CarIDs,',') 

    SET @query = N'
        select *
        from 
(
            SELECT *, row_number() over(order by  Plate_Number,'+@ColumnSort+' '+@OrderSort+') as rownumber2
            FROM (
                    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CarID ORDER BY Start_Time DESC) AS rownumber1
                    ,   cp.* 
                    FROM    [dbo].CarsParking cp
                    INNER JOIN #IDs ids
                        ON  ids.ID = cp.CarID
                    WHERE   EndTimeParking BETWEEN @StartTime  AND @EndTime 
                ) x
            WHERE x.rownumber1 = 1 -- Take last car post
            ) y
        WHERE  rownumber2 > @FirstRec -- Sort
        AND rownumber2 < @LastRec '
    
    exec sp_executesql @query 
    ,   N'@starttime INT, @endtime INT, @FirstRec INT, @LastRec INT'
    , @StartTime = @StartTime, @EndTime = @EndTime, @FirstRec = @FirstRec, @LastRec = @LastRec
END
GO

-- test code
exec report_parking 1, 30,111, 222, 'test,', 'test2', '1,2,3,4'
```

I like to put the IDs into temp table with index so the join is fast.

For the dynamic query, i pass the variables as parameters instead of building whole SQL string like you do. In some cases your version is faster, but it's usually better to parametrise things.

Finally, to handle sort and paging, i do two row_numbers, first to remove duplicates from cars, and second to properly sort them by pages. This part might be slow but hopefully you have few rows in the @CarIDs list so this won't be a huge problem

The query is a bit untested but you should be able to get the general idea